# grep values in quotation (regEx)

Tags: regex, grep

I'm tryng to parse a file using grep searching for the value in quotation marks:

---

output.txt

... junk .... productID=**'keyboad - mod A3025'** ... junk ....

---

in the file I want to use grep (egrep in windows) to get the value in quotation: ***keyboad - mod A3025***

what would be the expression to extract the value in **productID** without the quotes?

thanks!

---

worked using the below:

> grep.exe -aiPo "productID=\'(.*?)\'" output.txt

output:

> productID='keyboad - mod A3025'

now, how do i get rid of **productID=** and quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ echo "... junk .... productID='keyboad - mod A3025' ... junk ....'next' ... junk" | ruby -e 'puts gets.scan(/\47(.*?)\47/)'
keyboad - mod A3025
next
```

Or using GNU grep

```
$ echo "... junk .... productID='keyboad - mod A3025' ... junk ....'next' ... junk" | grep -Po '(productID=)\47(.*?)\47' | grep -Po '\47(.*?)\47'
'keyboad - mod A3025'
```

Comment: the system is windows. i'm looking for something more like grep only. i don't know what is inside the quotation. i only know the field is **productID**. C:\>grep <REGEX> output.txt

Comment: it actually worked using    grep.exe -aPo "\47(.*?)\47" output.txt    but it retrieved other field's values, not only productID

Comment: you can download GNU grep for windows as well. You can grep for productID first, then pass to another grep process to get what you want. see my amendments